# Does the stem function in R handle large counts correctly?

Tags: r, plot

I am wondering if the `stem` function in R is producing the stem and leaf plot correctly for this example. The code

```
X <- c(rep(1,1000),2:15)
stem(X,width = 20)
```

produces the output

```
  The decimal point is at the |

   1 | 00000000+980
   2 | 0
   3 | 0
   4 | 0
   5 | 0
   6 | 0
   7 | 0
   8 | 0
   9 | 0
  10 | 0
  11 | 0
  12 | 0
  13 | 0
  14 | 0
  15 | 0
```

There are 1000 ones in the data, but the output of the `stem` function seems to indicate that there are 988 ones (if you count the zeros in the first row and add 980). Instead of +980, I think it should display +992 at the end of the first row.

Is there an error in the `stem` function or am I not reading the output correctly?